# How to get data from an API which requires parameters from a previous API request in Angular 2?

Tags: api, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm writing a simple Angular 2 application which links to an API. The API has the endpoints:

> /job/:id
>
> /client/:id

I'd like my application to display a table with the following data:

> Job name
>
> Job description
>
> Client name
>
> Client email

I have a simple component to display this information

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {JobService} from './job.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'job',
    template: `
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Job Name: {{job.name}}</td>
    <td>Job Description: {{job.description}}</td>
    <td>Client Name: {{client.name}}</td>
    <td>Client Email: {{client.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>`,
    providers: [JobService]
})
export class JobComponent{
    job = {};
    client = {};


    constructor(private _jobService: JobService){}

    ngOnInit(){

        this._jobService.getJob(1)
            .subscribe(job => {
                this.job = job;
            });

        this._jobService.getClient(this.job.client_id)
            .subscribe(client => {
                this.client = client;
            });
    }
}
```

and the following service

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'


@Injectable()
export class JobService {


    constructor(private _http: Http){
    }

    getJob(id){
        return this._http.get(window.__env.apiUrl + 'job/' + id + '/')
        .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getClient(id){
        return this._http.get(window.__env.apiUrl + 'client/' + id + '/')
        .map(res => res.json());
    }


}
```

This writes the information from the job API call to the table correctly, but returns an error for the client information as both API calls run at the same time, thus the system hasn't received the client_id from the job API call yet. So I'm wondering what is the correct way in Angular to make this second API call after the completion of the first.

For reference sake here is the error:

> EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:8080/au/api/client/undefined/

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [flatMap/mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to run in sequence

```
ngOnInit(){

    this._jobService.getJob(1)
      .map(res => {
        this.job = job;
        return this.job.client_id;
      })
      .flatMap(client_id => this._jobService.getClient(client_id))
      .subscribe(client => {
          this.client = client;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the second call inside the first call. After getting the `job`, execute the second api call

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {JobService} from './job.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'job',
    template: `
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Job Name: {{job.name}}</td>
    <td>Job Description: {{job.description}}</td>
    <td>Client Name: {{client.name}}</td>
    <td>Client Email: {{client.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>`,
    providers: [JobService]
})
export class JobComponent{
    job = {};
    client = {};


    constructor(private _jobService: JobService){}

    ngOnInit(){

        this._jobService.getJob(1)
            .subscribe(job => {
                this.job = job;

                this._jobService.getClient(this.job.client_id)
                    .subscribe(client => {
                       this.client = client;
                    });
            });


    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement re try logic with this example? for instance these calls were in a function or form submit click - the second call failed for whatever reason and the user clicks submit again - could you start from the second call instead of the beginning? thanks

Comment: With that case not, but you can see `Observable.replay` function for replaying the calls